# Why array.push does not work on collection holding table data in Angular4 and PrimeNG?

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

So having following markup:

```
<p-dataTable
                                    selectionMode="single"
                                    [(selection)]="selectedUsers"
                                    dataKey="id"
                                    [value]="users"
                                    [rows]="25" [paginator]="users.length>25" [pageLinks]="3"
                                    [rowsPerPageOptions]="[10,25,50,100]"
                                   >
```

I am doing the following action to add record to table

```
applySelectedUsers() {
    // this.users.push(this.selectedUserToAdd);
    let arr=[];
    arr.push(this.selectedUserToAdd);
    this.users=this.users.concat(arr);
    this.selectedUserToAdd=null;
    this.hideUsersDialog();
}
```

My question is, why commented line does not work? Record is not visible in table despite `console.log(this.users)` showing that collection is growing after each push

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PrimeNG's datable looks for changes in reference so it expects immutable data.
If you don't need to take advantage over what immutability gives you just set `[immutable]` property of `p-dataTable` to **false**. But keep in mind that it will force the datatable to check the collection you bound to the `[value]` property on every ngDoCheck lifecycle resulting in performance drop.

You can nicely see the reason why it's not changing in the view in the source code

```
 set value(val:any[]) { // this will be triggered only by reassigning to this.users
        if(this.immutable) {
            this._value = val ? [...val] : null;  
            this.handleDataChange();
        }
        else {
            this._value = val;
        }

        this.valueChange.emit(this.value);
    }
```

now if you never reassign and set `[immutable]` to **false** it will check the differences in the lifecycle

```
    ngDoCheck() {
    if(!this.immutable) {
        let changes = this.differ.diff(this.value);
        if(changes) {
            this.handleDataChange();
        }
    }
}
```

I hope I helped. Have a nice day and don't React :)

Comment: allright, is it possible to "force" update? I feel that to be more convinient to push a row and trigger update then juggling around with array concatenation and replace .

Comment: I unfortunately can't think of any good ones. You could detach the change detector from the component that is using the datatable (but this has a lot of consequences), set the immutable to false and then run this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges() so it would run the doCheck in the datatable only when you want

Comment: Allright so that does not makes things easier I guess :). Mabe setting immutable to false is the way to go, after all there will not be much data in table. Thanks!

Comment: or maybe use `VisualChild` get the refrence to the instance of the datable component and run the `handleDataChange()` method when you push your row. It's public so you shouldn't need any javascript prototype shenanigans

Comment: Now we are talking. Let me check that right if it will work

Comment: unfortunetly no go, this does not makes UI to update ;(